# How to read Client Certificate from Belgian eID in Wildfly?

Tags: java, php, apache, wildfly, eid

I'd like to read some basic parameters from a Belgian eid card from the browser. (e.g. Name, serialNumber).

In a PHP application on Apache I know that enabling `SSLVerifyCLient` and adding `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars` provides some parameters (e.g. `$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN']`) to the application.

How would the same be achieved in a Java web application on Wilfly (15+)?